# A simple list format copying down

Tags: excel

I simply cannot figure out how to do this and would greatly appreciate any help. All I want to do it copy down the formula like this into the cells below:

```
`=c75'
`=D75'
`=E75'
```

and

```
`=C41'
`=D41'
`=E41'
```

So I will have a list of =C75 to =GN75, and the same for =C41 to =GN41

I want to copy it down to column GN. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Could you include a more clear example of your current data and expected output?  Your question is a bit confusing right now.

Comment: So you want the copy down to increment on column not row?

Comment: im basically just trying to copy down a list into each cell, starting with =c75, =d75, =e75, =f75... and so on, but when i drag the cells down it just inputs =c75, =c76, =c77 etc which is wrong

Comment: yes i want to copy down to increment on column, not row. I've already tried using $ symbols and to no avail

Comment: You could increment across the columns and then transpose the values.

Comment: maybe you are looking for the TRANSPOSE function?
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027

Comment: i can just copy rightwards and it works, but i want to copy it downwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=OFFSET($C$41,0,ROW()-95)
```

This formula would go in row 95. You have to change the `-95` part if you want it in a different row.

The `OFFSET` formula start at C41. It moves zero rows up/down, meaning it stays in row 41. The last argument, the column offset, changes as you copy the formula down. On row 95, it evaluates to zero, so the formula returns what's in C41 (C41 offset zero rows and zero columns is C41).

As you copy down to row 96, the column offset argument will change to 1 (row 96 - row 95). That will offset C41 one column to D41.

Answer (score 0):

This is for row # **41**.  Pick a cell and enter:

```
=INDEX($41:$41,1,ROWS($1:3))
```

then copy down:

[image]